# Is it possible to drill a CPU cleanly with a plasma cutter?

Tags: cutting

I would like to know if it is possible to cut a clean hole into a standard CPU with a plasma cutter, without damaging the plasma cutter.

I am making CPU keychains but I need to drill a hole through them first. If it is possible, it would make it way more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use a diamond drill bit. Cheap plated bits are good to learn on, but if you're doing it a lot, invest in sintered. Look at a lapidary or jeweler supply store/site or eBay

Answer (score 0):

You are going to be much better off with a water-cutter. Plasma cuts tend to splatter and soften the material around the edges of the cut, flaring them out.

Comment: I know that, but that can be sanded off. My question is that if it will cut it to begin with because I don't think the silicone in it always conducts electricity.